# Tense of "She is all I need"

Tags: tenses

It sounds like present progressive, but I'm not sure - it's also not a progressive 'verb'. I can see this hapening with other examples as well; and to some of them you even add `ed`, which makes me wonder even more:

1. She is all I need
2. The people of the neighborhood are nice
3. He is prejudiced
4. She is educated
5. It is cool

I'm not a native English speaker, and I'm not sure what to look for online to get an explanation on this thing. These are plain adjectives, right? Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how exactly this works, grammatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the simple present (or non-past) tense. There is no progressive aspect. Rather, in each sentence, the verb *to be* is followed by a subject complement, comprised of an adjective, past participle form, or noun phrase. A subject complement completes the meaning of the subject. 'She is' does not tell us much about the subject. The present tense here is unrestricted in meaning, in that the statement is seen as 'always' true. Compare 2 + 2 is 4.

The -ed words in your examples are the past participle verb forms used as adjectives.

Comment: That's what I needed, thanks! Could you elaborate on the `ed` though?

Comment: -ed is the past participle form of a verb; it is functioning as an adjective.

Comment: I did some research and finally found that I was referring to adjectives that describe emotions, so they end with `ed`. Enthralled, terrified, etc... Thanks :)